# Java - Array of Objects to HashSet

Tags: java, arrays, set

I've got following array:

```
private static Optreden[] optredens = {
            new Optreden("Editors", "Main Stage", 16, 0, 4),
            new Optreden("Empire of the Sun", "Pyramid Marquee", 23, 45, 5),
            new Optreden("Florence and the Machine", "Marquee", 18, 45, 3),
            new Optreden("The Specials", "Marquee", 13, 10, 5),
            new Optreden("Muse", "Main Stage", 19, 0, 5),
            new Optreden("Faithless", "Main Stage", 14, 30, 5),
            new Optreden("Absynthe Minded", "Pyramid Marquee", 21, 45, 5),
            new Optreden("Pink", "Main Stage", 20, 30, 2),
            new Optreden("Editors", "Marquee", 21, 20, 4),
            new Optreden("Faithless", "Pyramid Marquee", 19, 0, 5)
            };
```

The Optreden object constructor looks like this:

```
Optreden(name, stage, hour, minutes, rating);
```

Now, I have to create a HashSet of the Optreden objects BUT it may not contain duplicate names, so when I print the HashSet it has to look like this:

```
The Specials (Marquee, 13u10)--> *****
Empire of the Sun (Pyramid Marquee, 23u45)--> *****
Florence and the Machine (Marquee, 18u45)--> ***
Pink (Main Stage, 20u30)--> **
Muse (Main Stage, 19u)--> *****
Absynthe Minded (Pyramid Marquee, 21u45)--> *****
Editors (Main Stage, 16u)--> ****
Faithless (Main Stage, 14u30)--> *****
```

Thing is, I can't edit the Optreden class and it only has a constructor and a toString method, no getName() getter.

How can I pull this off? Thanks.

Comment: what about using a Map using name as key?... In the end, a HashSet is just a HashMap whose keys and values are the same object.

Comment: This looks more like an organisational issue than a technical one, and we can only help you with technical workarounds... Can you subclass Optreden for example? Or if all else fails, reflection disregards visibility at a cost in code readability, type safety, and runtime performance.

Comment: Seems to me like the design of your class Optreden (performance -as in musical- in english) is the src of the issue. A compliant javabean design with getters, setters, equals() & hashcode will get you far enough. e.g. given that your requirement is a set, you could use a TreeSet with a custom Comparator to achieve  your goal.  If all you've got is a toString() method, I'd create a proper JavaBean for Optreden using a String constructor. Use that to parse the toString() output of the ill-designed original class, and provide the right implementation for the equals() and hashcode() methods.

Comment: Hmmm, an organizer of Rock Werchter :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `Optreden` is not a `final` class, you can subclass it to trap `name` in the constructor and implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` to use `name`, as follows:

```
public class MyOptreden extends Optreden
{
    private String name;

    public MyOptreden(String name, String stage, int hour, int minutes, int rating) {
        super(name, stage, hour, minutes, rating);
        this.name = name; // A capture name here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof MyOptreden && ((MyOptreden) obj).name.equals(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

As long as you are using only instances of this class in your set, it will work.

You will have to override `setName()`, if it exists, to update `name`.

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to be a HashSet? If you're happy to use a TreeSet instead, create one with a custom comparator that compares the names. Something like (not compiled or tested!):

```
Comparator<Optreden> compareByName = new Comparator<Optreden>() {
    public int compare(Optreden a, Optreden b) {
        return getName(a).compareTo(getName(b));
    }
    private String getName(Optreden o) {
        String s = o.toString();
        return s.substring(0, (s.indexOf('(') - 1);
    }
}

Set<Optreden> optredensUniqueByName = new TreeSet<Optreden>(compareByName);
optredensUniqueByName.addAll(Arrays.asList(optredens));
```

Comment: @maasg: Thank you. Our solutions are pretty much the same - mine may be slightly neater, but yours was two minutes quicker!

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comment.  Under the current restrictions given in the original question i.e. only a constructor and a toString() method available, you could create a set, using an ordered Set (e.g. TreeSet) and a custom `Comparator` implementation. Your Comparator implementation will then use the only accessor method `Optreden.toString()` to parse the name of the group.
e.g.

```
class OptredenComparator implements Comparator<Optreden> {
...

 int compare(Optreden o1, Optreden o2) {
     // this is to illustrate the logic. Mind the nulls
     String name1 = o1.split("(")[0];
     String name2 = o2.split("(")[0];
     return name1.compareTo(name2);
 }
...
}
```

You can then create a `TreeSet(new OptredenComparator)` and add your instances of Optreden to it.

*I would like to emphasize that although this is the answer to the original question, the root issue that need to be addressed is the design of the class being used as data container (Optreden)*

}

Comment: A) You should never reply on `toString()` output in your code. B) a comparator is not useful to a Set - you need equals(). see my answer

Comment: @Bohemian A) toString() Agreed. I warned about the solution in the first place, but that's what the OP gave as only instruments to access that class. I assumed no access to the place where the objects are created, otherwise, why not roll you own class?  B) regarding to the `Comparator`, it is a valid option.Please see [http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html](SortedSet).